# Fix Dual Boot MBR using Boot Repair

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot

OK..Mine is a Corporate Laptop. I had Windows 7 and Ubuntu working perfectly. Just today McAfee Safeboot modified the MBR and moment I boot the McAfee Endpoint Encryption screen pops in. Although I am 100% sure that my disks aren't encrypted since I have not yet set the username and password for McAfee and since I boot from Live Ubuntu CD I can see all the drives.

1. I simply want to overwrite the MBR and make it dual boot again. Can I do it using Boor Repair?
2. What if I reinstall Ubuntu 64bit (Old was 32 bit) using the option "Reinstall Ubuntu. This will delete your files videos pictures and documents". Even that should rewrite the MBR in dual boot mode and install Ubuntu 64 bit which I anyway wanted to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yes you can do that via boot-repair.
2) You can do that as well, however I do recommend trying to fix the booting itself with boot-repair first.

Comment: Thanks ! Helped. This time i got the backup of 512 bytes using the dd command. Next ill have to fix this McAfee thing by uninstalling.